# Application taking too much space in RAM causing the app to close

Tags: blackberry, cordova, sencha-touch, sybase, blackberry-webworks

I'm having a problem with the app I'm building  the RAM of the **BB 9800** is too small.

I have a html5 application that I use in IOS and Blackberry.
I'm using `phonegap plugin` to pull data form server by using `Sybase`.

On IOS everything runs fine but on blackberry I frequently get a message *"low on memory, please stop applications"* and the only app running is mine. And usually this is followed by *"app closing because its too big"*.

> How can I either increase the memory available for my app (unlikely)
>   or decrease the amount my app is using (tips and guide lines)

I'm using:

- `Sencha Touch` for our interface
- `Phonegap` to access the native api
- `Sybase` to do the sync between our local data and the server data
- No toolkits - only one is sencha touch
- everything is loaded at index.html - no ajax at all
- index.html is a local file - no request loading

Sencha does the `DOM` stuff - not all screens in one main DOM - the screens are created on demand.

Comment: So, i'm facing a similar problem. Which was the solution? splitting into different pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you pull data from Sybase - is that when you get that memory error?

Unfortunately sencha/phonegap/sybase sync/your js will take memory (specially since it's all in one page), and those frameworks are big enough to cause troubles...

My suggestions:

1. if the error happens only when you load data, the question is how much data are you loading? maybe it's trying to download 1gb of data and trying to do that in memory? I would look into server-side paging to reduce your data-footprint
2. try to split into multiple .html pages each doing a subset of the work you are now doing in one big file...

Hope this helps